# How to add 10 mins to DateTime variable every 3 hours

Tags: c#, loops

So basically, I have a plane object with a range (in hours) of 3. So every 3 hours the plane is supposed to stop for fuel for 10 minutes. I have been trying to make a counter and add the additional difference to it in minutes and compare it that way to plane.Range but Im not having any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse(inputTime); // in format "18/05/2019 11:00:00 PM"
List<DateTime> temporaryTimes = new List<DateTime>();
temporaryTimes.Add(startTime); // Add initial value "23:00
List<string> timeStrings = new List<string>();

DateTime count = DateTime.Parse("00:00:00");

for (int i = 0; i < distanceTotal.Length; i++)
{
    if (count.Hour < plane1.Range)
    {
        temporaryTimes.Add(startTime.AddMinutes((Tour.CalTime(distanceTotal[i], plane1))));
        count = count.AddMinutes((Tour.CalTime(distanceTotal[i], plane1)));
        // string stringVersion = startTime.ToString("HH:mm");
        // timeStrings.Add(stringVersion);
        startTime = (startTime.AddMinutes((Tour.CalTime(distanceTotal[i], plane1))));
        var nextTime = temporaryTimes[i].AddMinutes((Tour.CalTime(distanceTotal[i], plane1)));

    }

    if (count.Hour >= plane1.Range)
    {
        DateTime test = temporaryTimes[i].AddMinutes(10);
        temporaryTimes.Add(test);
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
18/05/2019 11:00:00 PM
18/05/2019 11:28:00 PM
19/05/2019 12:10:00 AM
19/05/2019 12:44:00 AM
19/05/2019 1:30:00 AM
19/05/2019 2:04:00 AM
19/05/2019 1:40:00 AM
19/05/2019 2:14:00 AM
```

Expected output **(note the 10 min break at 1:30 - 1:40)**:

```
18/05/2019 11:00:00 PM
18/05/2019 11:28:00 PM
19/05/2019 12:10:00 AM
19/05/2019 12:44:00 AM
19/05/2019 1:30:00 AM
19/05/2019 1:40:00 AM
19/05/2019 2:15:00 AM
19/05/2019 3:00:00 AM
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean. The sounds like you want something to happen every three hours on a timer, but it's not that. So it's unclear what you mean by "every three hours." It's difficult to relate what you're asking to what we see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

within your second `if` block you should increment the `startTime` as well in order to keep the `startTime` updated after the break time.

something like this:

```
if (count.Hour >= plane1.Range)
{
    startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(10);
    temporaryTimes.Add(startTime);
}
```